# Различие вызовов методов JavaScript

Tags: ооп, объекты, javascript, методы

Ребят, помогите понять в чем вообще разница таких вызовов? Встречаю в коде разных людей разные способы и никак не могу вникнуть в преимущества каждого из этих способов :/

```
var obj = {
    some_method: function(){
        return 'This works';
    }
}

var Obj2 = function(){
    return {
        some_method: function(){
            return 'This works too';
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj.some_method());

var obj3 = new Obj2();
console.log(obj3.some_method());
```

Оба способа вернут то что и должны, вот [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kRBY/) но вот в каких случаях какой вариант применять?

Comment: Ну первый короче)

Comment: Второй метод - это паттерн "фабрика". Если появилось желание понять разницу, - значит самое время изучать паттерны проектирования.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на свой же вопрос

первый способ это просто объект с методом внутри
второй способ это недомодуль, если обернуть в Obj2 = (function(){ ... }()); то получится модуль и перед return можно напихать приватных свойств методов, а те что пожелаешь сделать публичными - вынести через return, тогда к ним можно будет обратиться через Obj2.название_метода

Comment: По другому это называется - замыкание

Answer (score 0):

что вам удобнее читать и отлаживать, то и применяйте